# How to access PHP based service in Metro style app

Tags: c#, php, service, microsoft-metro

we have a web service which will be used by the application to interact with the Server.

This service is a PHP based service. When we add this as a service reference in metro style app we aren’t able to do access any methods.

We tried the same URL in other application as a service reference and we were able to access the methods.

The service URL is http://sanity-free.org/services/ws.php?wsdl

Please let me know how can we access this method in our application.

Thanks

Mani

Answer (score 0):

I'll describe you my case. I hope it helps.

I have a metro app that communicates with azure sql via asp webapi. The webapi is hosted in cloud and it is a connector for metro to my db.

It is very simillar to your case. Create public methods that are available from world. Than you need just to make sure that the data are returned in a good format (by your php service). I'm prefering json cause it is easy to code,decode ant it's lite (that is very important in a webapp).

I connect with my api this: http://domain.com/api/Content/get or http://domain.com/api/content/getbyname/my+name

With this urls I'll get whole content or content by title

This is not a 100% answer for your question but can solve it :)